# register sidebar in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a html template and I have this code in my html and wants to convert this in **wordpress**

```html
<div id="home">
          <!-- Home Page -->
        <p class="blue">NEED A DESIGNER?</p>
        <p class="orange">I AM HERE</p>
        <span><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i>&nbsp;+1 234 567 876 54</span>
          <!-- / Home Page -->
    </div>
```

I want to call this as `dynamic_sidebar();` ....

how i can register sidebar in functions.php file...

I tried as following

```html
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'homepage_widget' );
function homepage_widget() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'main homepage', 'theme-slug' ),
        'id' => 'homepagelol',
        'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on all posts and pages.', 'theme-slug' ),
        'class'     => 'orange',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="home">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<p class="blue">',
    'after_title'   => '</div>',
    ) );
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would not want to create it as a HTML Widget?

Comment: Yeah, just put the above html in the Text widget on your site in your created `main homepage` sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few steps you need to follow:

Step 1 : Register your sidebar

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'theme_slug_widgets_init' );
function theme_slug_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'theme-slug' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on all posts and pages.', 'theme-slug' ),
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
```

Step 2: In widget Area, you see your sidebar, then add text widget and put your html in text widget

Step 3: Then call your sidebar in index.php

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('your-sidebar-unique-id'); ?>
```

Then save your page and reload..
Hope this will help you.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to register sidebar, hope it helps.

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'MiddleSidebar',
'before_widget' => '<li class="widget">',
'after_widget' => '</li>',
'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
'after_title' => '</h3>',
));
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'FooterSidebar',
'before_widget' => '<li class="widget">',
'after_widget' => '</li>',
'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
'after_title' => '</h3>',
));
```